# Date format error in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime

I get this error when I run the application `Incorrect syntax near 12`, on debugging I found that this error is caused due to the # along with the date.

```
Dim backdate as datetime
backdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
```

on binding the data to the grid to filter the backdate records this error is caused **Incorrect syntax near 12**.

```
myqry =  " select SRNO,SUBJECT,ID where datesend =" backdate
```

Now i am trying to extract only the date or shall I divide the date into day , month and year with `DATEPART` and take into a variable or convert the date  or what should i do , Please help ???

Comment: You need to use parameters.  What database are you connecting to?

Comment: Does datesend field in the database include time?

Comment: yes , for example for today the field is 2010-04-19 13:58:52.000

Comment: Thank you, I've changed my answer to ignore the time.

Comment: Thank you all...oh Im loving this site !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct statement:

```
myqry = "select SRNO,SUBJECT,ID where cast(convert(char(10), datesend, 121) as datetime) ='" & backdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
```

Cast and Convert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Convert with parameter 121 will convert to the following format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h), from that string, we get the first 10 characters (char(10)).

Without parameters:

```
myqry = "Select SRNO,SUBJECT,ID From ... Where convert(char(10), datesend, 121) = convert(char(10), dateadd(day,-1,getdate()), 121)"
```

Comment: ('yyyy-MM-dd') & "'" is being disabled when i use this statement ??

Comment: sorry sorry sorry .....i got this ...perfect buddy !! thanks a million . But one thing i wanted to know abt "121" in the above statement?

Comment: also , how can I use this "SELECT DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE())" , i think this will also give the same result like the above. If i want to use this for instance so how should i filter like " where datesend = (SELECT DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE())) " ?? will this be correct ?

Comment: I've modified my answer to include a query without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are missing the ampersand (`&`) in your query. Also, try putting your date in quotes in the query:

```
myqry =  " select SRNO,SUBJECT,ID where datesend ='" & backdate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') & "'"
```

Comment: shukriya Sarfraz bhai , I really appreciate your help .

Answer (score 0):

myqry =  " select SRNO,SUBJECT,ID where datesend = '" & backdate.tostring("dd MMMM yyyy") & "'"